# Prove that $\int g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx$.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f:[0,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ and $g:]0,b]\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ define as $$g(x)=\int_x^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dt.$$

Prove that $g$ is integrable and that $$\int g(x)dx=\int f(x)dx.$$

So $$\int g(x)dx=\int_0^b\int_x^b\frac{f(t)}{t}dtdx$$
I would like to use tonelli, but I can't since the integral inside depend on $x$. Is there a trick here ?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

To use Tonelli, your function needs to be positive. Moreover, to prove the integrability, you need to prove that $\int|g|<\infty $, not $\int g<\infty $. So take the absolute value !

$$\int_0^b\int_x^b \frac{|f(t)|}{t}\mathrm d t\mathrm d x=\int_0^b\int_0^b\frac{|f(t)|}{t}\boldsymbol 1_{\{0\leq x\leq t\leq b\}}\mathrm d t\mathrm d x.$$

I think you will have no difficulties to continue from here.